# Как вывести пару объектов массива сразу

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли вывести сразу несколько объектов массива?

Есть массив:

```
let a = [2, 'hello', 17, 34, 'privet'];
console.log(a[0,3]);
```

Он выводит последний объект, который указан то-есть: `3(17)`.

Возможно ли вывести сразу два объекта, чтобы не копировать код?

```
console.log(a[0]);
console.log(a[3]);
```

Comment: `console.log(a[0], a[3]);`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Можно еще console.table(a) - отобразит данные всего массива, с индексами